# Inconsistent handling of lonely PSUs in R's `survey` package?

Tags: r, sampling, survey, stratification, subset

There appears to be some inconsistent handling of lonely PSUs in R's `survey` package when calling `svyglm` on a subset of stratified data where the act of subsetting creates the lonely PSU. It appears that the sample size associated with a lonely PSU in a stratum does not change when using the `subset.survey.design` method, which means that `svyglm` runs without throwing an error indicating that the lonely PSU exists. Is it correct for `svyglm` to do so in that circumstance?

To further demonstrate the issue, I first create a dummy survey dataset.

```
library(survey)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(9001)

# create random weights and rescale to add up to 1
wts = runif(1000, 1, 1000)
wts = wts/sum(wts)

# create dummy survey dataset for testing lonely PSU subsets
test_svy_data <- tibble(id = 1:1000, a = rnorm(1000), b = rnorm(1000), 
                        group = c(rep("a",999), "b"), wt = wts, 
                        strat = c(rep(1,333),rep(2,333),
                                  rep(3,332), c(4,4)))
```

This creates a dataset where subsetting to `group == "a"` creates a lonely PSU in stratum 4.

I then construct two `survey.design` objects using different ways of subsetting: 1) Filter the initial dataset so that the lonely PSU already exists, then create a `survey.design` object; and 2) Use the `subset.survey.design` method built into the survey package after creating a `survey.design` object, thereby producing the lonely PSU.

```
# create stratified survey from initial data with lonely PSU
test_svy1 <- svydesign(data = test_svy_data %>% filter(group == "a"),
                       ids = ~id, weights = ~wt, strata = ~strat)

# create stratified survey from initial data without lonely PSU, then subset
test_svy2 <- svydesign(data = test_svy_data,
                       ids = ~id, weights = ~wt, 
                       strata = ~strat) %>%
  subset(group == "a")
```

Next, I attempt to run `svyglm` using both of these test objects. The first test produces the expected lonely PSU error as per the survey package's [documentation](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/exmample-lonely.html) on lonely PSUs when using the default handling.

```
> try(test1 <- svyglm(a~b, test_svy1) %>% summary())
Error in onestrat(x[index, , drop = FALSE], clusters[index], nPSU[index][1],  : 
  Stratum (4) has only one PSU at stage 1
```

The second runs without any errors.

```
> try(test2 <- svyglm(a~b, test_svy2) %>% summary())
> # no error
```

The difference appears to arise from the `fpc$sampsize` component of the `survey.design` objects. In the first test, the sample size associated with each PSU is correct, per the following code and output. A sample size of one is associated with the lonely PSU.

```
> test_svy1$fpc$sampsize %>% table()
.
  1 332 333 
  1 332 666
```

But after using `subset.survey.design`, the `fpc$sampsize` component still has a sample size of 2 associated with the lonely PSU.

```
> test_svy2$fpc$sampsize %>% table() 
.
  2 332 333 
  1 332 666
# appears to still have a sample size of 2 assigned to the lonely PSU
```

Assigning a value of 1 to the fpc$sampsize component of the `survey.design` object for the lonely PSU, then calling `svglm` using the new values restores the error:

```
> # try replacing fpc attribute with one for the lonely PSU
> test_svy3 <- test_svy2
> 
> # Assign corrected(?) fpc value
> test_svy3$fpc$sampsize[999,1] <- 1
> 
> # throws lonely PSU error
> try(test3 <- svyglm(a~b, test_svy3) %>% summary())
Error in onestrat(x[index, , drop = FALSE], clusters[index], nPSU[index][1],  : 
  Stratum (4) has only one PSU at stage 1
```

Is the package handling the lonely PSU created by a subset correctly in the first test? Or the second test? Both somehow?

[I *have* compared this handling to Stata's `svyset` approach. Stata warns about a lonely PSU regardless of when the subsetting occurs.]

Also for reference, here's the output from `packageDescription("survey")` run on my machine.

```
Package: survey
Title: Analysis of Complex Survey Samples
Description: Summary statistics, two-sample tests, rank tests, generalised linear models,
          cumulative link models, Cox models, loglinear models, and general maximum
          pseudolikelihood estimation for multistage stratified, cluster-sampled,
          unequally weighted survey samples. Variances by Taylor series linearisation or
          replicate weights. Post-stratification, calibration, and raking. Two-phase
          subsampling designs. Graphics. PPS sampling without replacement.
Version: 4.1-1
Author: Thomas Lumley
Maintainer: "Thomas Lumley" <t.lumley@auckland.ac.nz>
License: GPL-2 | GPL-3
Depends: R (>= 3.5.0), grid, methods, Matrix, survival
Imports: stats, graphics, splines, lattice, minqa, numDeriv, mitools (>= 2.4)
Suggests: foreign, MASS, KernSmooth, hexbin, RSQLite, quantreg, parallel, CompQuadForm,
          DBI, AER
URL: http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/
NeedsCompilation: no
Packaged: 2021-07-16 23:50:34 UTC; tlum005
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2021-07-19 08:40:04 UTC
Built: R 3.6.0; ; 2022-09-07 21:44:31 UTC; unix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between lonely PSUs created by design (i.e., when a stratum only has one PSU sampled) and lonely PSUs created by subsetting to a domain (referred to as "domain lonely PSUs" in the terminology of the survey package).

Unbiased variance estimation for design-lonely PSUs is not generally possible for design-lonely PSUs, but for domain-lonely PSUs, variance estimation for totals is still unbiased. This is why the survey package quite sensibly doesn't throw errors for domain lonely PSUs but does throw errors for design-lonely PSUs.

If you're using the `option(survey.lonely.psu = 'adjust')` to handle design-lonely PSUs, you can use `options(survey.adjust.domain.lonely = TRUE)` to have this special handling used for domain-lonely PSUs as well. However, at the present moment, some caution is warranted around using `option(survey.lonely.psu = 'adjust')` as [it has a bug when estimating population totals.](https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/bugs-with-singleton-strata/). I think this will get fixed soon and I'll update this answer when it does.

The handling of lonely PSUs is documented in the survey package in a help file accessible in R by running `help("survey.lonely.psu", package = "survey")`.